# Check Box VBA does not save

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code below is meant to allow only certain users to tick & un-tick a checkbox. However, the problem is that if I check the box and then close the spreadsheet, when I re-open the excel file the 'tick' is no longer there. It's like the code does not save the 'tick' action. Basically, if I check the box I want that to stay like that, even after closing the spreadsheet. In the VBA code below i added ThisWorkbook.Save in order to save the "Tick" action but it simply saves the spreadsheet instead of saving the "Tick" in the check box. Could you please advise what's wrong in my code? I've asked this question before but unfortunately nobody seemed to be able to find a solution. thanks so much

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
If (UCase(Environ("username")) = "TESTNAME") Then
  'Do nothing
Else
  'Uncheck because user not matching
  CheckBox1.Value = False
  MsgBox ("You are not authorized to tick this box.")
End If
End If
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this checkbox on a Userform or on the sheet? Is it an ActiveX control  or a Form control?

Comment: No we just need to know.

Comment: I think you must save tha state of the checkbox on a sheet (probably on a hidden one) - or in some other way that fits your needs

Comment: how can I do that? thanks

Comment: I agree with @tretom. Form controls have "Design-time" properties and "run-time" properties. It is not trivial at all to change the design-time properties in order to persist the runtime ones. Best is to manage it yourself; Save it in some hidden worksheet, some cell or some named range.

Comment: check my answer, I made a small example that might help (with many modifications according to your needs)

Comment: Duplicate of [check box vba does not stay ticked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852627/check-box-vba-does-not-stay-ticked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on my sheet1 I have a commandButton (bShow) and in the code behind:

```
Private Sub bShow_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

then I have a UserForm named UserForm1 with a checkbox (named checkBox1) and a button named saveButton, and with a code behind:

```
Private Sub saveButton_Click()
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

with this setup in cell("A1") appears TRUE or FALSE depending on the checkbox state

i hope it helps

EDIT1:

by opening the Form reading the value from the sheet:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

EDIT2:

be aware of error handling (eg.: what if cell value is neither TRUE nor FALSE) But that I leave to you

Comment: you can't have two `UserForm_Activate()` by the same userform. Simply write the two separate subs into one

`Private Sub UserForm_Activate() 
 User Form Position Me.StartUpPosition = 0 Me.Top = Application.Top + 165 Me.Left = Application.Width - Me.Width - 25 
 UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub`

(I haven't tested it)

Comment: something like that should be handled in `Sub Workbook_Open()` but it's hard to tell exactly without seeing the whole code

Comment: well, if you want to tell the user that she doesn't have the right to click on your checkbox, I would put the code for this checking-the-right into the checkbox_click code within the code of the form. seems to me being logic there

Comment: _"I don't understand why she's getting this message ALSO when she opens the spreadsheet?_" - it happens when you put that code into the workbook_open sub of the ThisWorkbook section in your workbook. Check it, if you have put that MsgBox there too. (Sorry for the lame explanation)

Comment: am glad to help